# Update URL from action filter ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hellp all,

Generally speaking I want to "update" URL from action filter in OnActionExecuting method. I registered action filter to be global and that method will be executed before every action is executed.

In OnActionExecuting method I am processing some things and I want to update URL with accountName after that.

I have configured routes which can accept four segments route patterns - something like these: {accountName}/{controller}/{action}, {controller}/{action}...

Basically if I receive request which doesn't contain {accountName} segment or if is that segment empty I would like to update URL with new accountName and be able to see updated URL when request is ended.

I am trying to do that like in following:

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values["accountName"] = accountName;
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("AccountRoute", filterContext.RouteData.Values);
```

I added new route data value to filterContext and after I am trying to redirect to specific route with route data values.

That approach doesn't properly because I am encountered with "TO MANY REQUESTS" and it broke my app.

Any idea how I can update URL and avoid to many requests?

Thanks